# How can I make an application runnable both as a WinForms app and console app through the VS Debugger, dependent on launch settings?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, .net-5, c#-9.0

I have an application that can be run as both console application and a WinForms.

MCVE code follows:

program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinFormsAndConsoleApp
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.SystemAware);
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            AttachConsole();
            if (args.Length >= 1 && args[0].Equals("--cli", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Running in CLI mode - console.");
                Debug.WriteLine("Running in CLI mode - debug.");
            }
            else
            {
                Application.Run(new Form1());
            }
            
        }

        // Attach to parent, so that output is displayed when running from command line.
        public static void AttachConsole()
        {
            AttachConsole(-1);
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool AttachConsole(int dwProcessId);
    }
}
```

Externally to VS, it works as expected. I can run it as a UI app by launching the exe or as console app from cmd using:

```
start/w "" "WinFormsAndConsoleApp.exe" --cli
```

However, the debugger will display an external Console window only if the output type is set to Exe. I only want the external console displaying when the app is running in cli mode.

One approach I've tried so far is using the following launch settings:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "WinFormsAndConsoleApp - UI": {
      "commandName": "Project"
    },
    "WinFormsAndConsoleApp - Console": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "commandLineArgs": "--cli",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "USE_EXTERNAL_CONSOLE": "true"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and the following csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <DisableWinExeOutputInference>true</DisableWinExeOutputInference>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(USE_EXTERNAL_CONSOLE)'=='true'">
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(USE_EXTERNAL_CONSOLE)'!='true'">
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="TestMessage" AfterTargets="Build" >
    <Message Text="use console is '$(USE_EXTERNAL_CONSOLE)'" Importance="high"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Unfortunately, USE_EXTERNAL_CONSOLE is always treated as the empty string.

Is this a good way of ensuring an external console is used on some launchsettings profiles and not others?

If so, how can I correct the communication between launchsettings and the csproj file?

If not, how else can I make the appearance of the external console dependent on whether the tool is being run from the console or through the UI?

Comment: Based on my test, I could not reproduce your problem. I even can not see an extra console window. Can you provide more details with me so that I can reproduce your problem?

Comment: Hi @Jack - sorry for the lack of clarity. The key point is that, with the above code the external console window does not appear even when USE_EXTERNAL_CONSOLE is set to 'true'. Just making the external console window appear is simple - I can switch the output type from WinExe to Exe. The hard part is making it appear only on certain launch settings. So, not seeing the external console appear under the 'WinFormsAndConsoleApp - Console' launch setting IS the issue. Are there any particular details that would be helpful to assist you?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion: create a new function with a Conditional Attribute set (`[Conditional("DEBUG")]`) on it. Next, in your Main, call this function. It will only execute while under the debugger. You could also do something similar with the `if (Debugger.IsAttached)` method. Whichever you choose, put any calls you want under this new arrangement. This way, you'll only see whatever you want while running under the debugger.

Here is an example:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Testing
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern bool FreeConsole();

        [Conditional("DEBUG")]
        public static void HideConsoleWhenDebug()
        {
            FreeConsole();
        }

        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length >= 1 && args[0].Equals("--cli", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                AttachConsole();
                Console.WriteLine("Running in CLI mode - console.");
            }
            else
            {
                // While under debugger, never show the console window
                HideConsoleWhenDebug();

                Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.SystemAware);
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new Form1());
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Having tried it out, it seems that the FreeConsole() command has no observable effect on the external console window launched by VS when the OutputType is Exe. Of course, the external console window will still never appear when the OutputType is WinExe. To ensure I wasn't misusing FreeConsole(), I copied your code directly and only added what was needed to make it compile. The presence of the console window is still only affected by the OutputType and not the call to FreeConsole().

Answer (score 0):

I now have a working solution using AllocConsole from kernel32.dll. I have also added in a "--same-window-cli" option so that a user can run the tool from a console window without creating a new one, if desired. I have removed all usage of the "USE_EXTERNAL_CONSOLE" environment variable, as it was not read correctly in the csproj file. The modified c# code for the Program class is shown below:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinFormsAndConsoleApp
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length >= 1)
            {
                if (args[0].Equals("--same-window-cli", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    CliSetup();
                    return;
                }
                else if (args[0].Equals("--cli", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    AllocConsole();
                    CliSetup();
                    return;
                }
            }

            Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.SystemAware);
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
            
        }

        // Attach to parent, so that output is displayed when running from command line.
        public static void AttachConsole()
        {
            AttachConsole(-1);
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool AttachConsole(int dwProcessId);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern bool AllocConsole();

        private static void CliSetup()
        {
            AttachConsole();
            Console.WriteLine("Running in CLI mode - console.");
            Debug.WriteLine("Running in CLI mode - debug.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```